# Mongodb Export Query using Wildcards?

Tags: mongodb, mongoexport

I have a mongo collection with documents with the following structure:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5db82cd948d57f69b83b5e59"),
    "sensor": {
        "_id": "123123",
        "type": "typeA"
    },
    "Object": {
        "_id": "lkj123",
        "type": "typeB"
    }
}
```

I need to export all documents for a list of sensor id's, but the corresponding sensor types are not included.

The following would work for 2 documents, but this would require me to first look up the corresponding types and the list of sensor id's are too long to do this manually.

```
mongoexport --uri="<MY-CONNECTION-STRING>" --collection="<MY-COLLECTION>" --out=MY-EXPORT.json -q="{$or:[{sensor:{_id : '123', type:'typeA'}},{sensor:{_id : 'abc', type:'typeB'}}]}"
```

I have tried to use wildcards for the sensor types, but I couldn't get it working properly.

How can I create a working query that allows me to just copy past the sensorid's in to do the trick?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not able to understand your question, what do you mean by "but the corresponding sensor types are not included"

Comment: "I have tried to use wildcards" you mean regexps? It should work. What did you try? You can actually use aggregation with $lookup if you create a view and then export it.

Comment: @PuneetSingh Say I have a sensor id: "123" I don't know what the sensor type is for that sensor. So I first have to look it up and than manually add it to the query for the export. I have tried to exlcude the sensor type in the query but then no documents are exported at all.

Comment: @AlexBlex I have tried to use * for the sensor types. I'm not that familiar with mongo. Do you have an example on how to do this in my case?

Comment: it's not a wildcard, it's an asterisk. Please get familiar with the query syntax https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/

Comment: If you tried to search sensor id alone as `{sensor:{_id : '123'}}` this will match sensors with _id 123 and **without** type. To find sensors with _id 123 and **any** type you need to query `{"sensor._id": "123"}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query will work when you only pass sensor id, just pass them in this format

```
mongoexport --uri="<MY-CONNECTION-STRING>" --collection="<MY-COLLECTION>" --out=MY-EXPORT.json -q="{$or:[{'sensor._id':'123'},{'sensor._id':'abc'}]}"
```

And if you have all the sensor's id in an array, I would prefer to use $in like below,

```
mongoexport --uri="<MY-CONNECTION-STRING>" --collection="<MY-COLLECTION>" --out=MY-EXPORT.json -q="{'sensor._id': {$in: ['123', 'abc']}}"
```

Both examples will work for you

Comment: Both examples work perfect, thanks! I've excepted your answer.

Comment: Happy to help :)